# How to delete all pictures of an directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I am trying to delete all pictures of an directory. But getting error on directory path. And also dont know how to get all pictures path & delete all of them.

My directory structure :

```
server
  -> app.js
tmp
  -upload
  -- pic.jpg
  -- pic2.jpg
  -- pic3.jpg
```

I have tried this :

```
var dir = require('../tmp/upload');
var fs = require('fs');
var promise = require('bluebird');
fs.readdir(dir).then(function(file) {
    console.log(data)

}).catch(function(err){
    console.log
})
```

But getting error : Cannot find module '../tmp/upload'

Need help to get the path & all pictures on upload folder & delete them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If app.js is on the same level as tmp then use ./tmp/upload instead. The .. will try and go outside of the folder the current code is executing within.

Comment: app.js is on server folder. upload folder is on tmp folder. So what will be the path ???

server
  -> app.js
tmp
  -upload
  -- pic.jpg

Comment: So app.js and tmp are in the same folder called server?

Comment: No app.js is in Server folder

tmp is just outside of server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got this error simply because you actually required a module from the relative path instead of resolving it. In order to resolve a relative path to an absolute path, you need to use `path.resolve`, not `require`.

```
var path = require('path');
var dir = path.resolve('../tmp/upload');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises 
// For ES syntax: import { promises as fsPromises } from 'fs'

const directory = 'your/directory/path/here'

await fsPromises.rmdir(directory, {
  recursive: true
})
```